# How to sort a SwiftUI table using custom logic?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Im trying to create a table using SwiftUI and following this - https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-multi-column-lists-using-table

```
struct User: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    var name: String
    var score: Int
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var users = [
        User(id: 1, name: "Taylor Swift", score: 95),
        User(id: 2, name: "Justin Bieber", score: 80),
        User(id: 3, name: "Adele Adkins", score: 85)
    ]
    @State private var sortOrder = [KeyPathComparator(\User.name)]
    @State private var selection: User.ID?

    var body: some View {
        Table(users, selection: $selection, sortOrder: $sortOrder) {
            TableColumn("Selected") {
                Toggle(isOn: viewModel.bindingForUser(user))
            }

            TableColumn("Name", value: \.name)
            TableColumn("Score", value: \.score) { user in
                Text(String(user.score))
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: sortOrder) { newOrder in
            users.sort(using: newOrder)
        }
    }
}
```

And added a new column called "Selected". Now how to sort the table using the new column? The column value isn't available in the model `User`

**EDIT**

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published
    var selectedUsers: [User] = []
    func bindingForUser(_ user: User) -> Binding<Bool> {
        .init(get: { selectedUsers.contains(user) },
              set: {
                  if $0 { selectedUsers.append(user) }
                  else { selectedUsers.remove(user) }
              })
    }
}
```

Comment: `viewModel.bindingForUser(user)`, we have no idea what this? The code snippet has no relevance to the rest of the posted code.

Comment: I don't really understand how that is implemented but you can't have sorting in a column where the value comes from a function. It needs to be a stored or computed property on User.

Comment: As I said, you can’t sort on this column.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort using this extraneous data if it is available in the program when you call sort. I found Apple's default sort too limiting for my program, and decided to sort the data myself. A partial example from my program:

```
    .onChange(of: sortOrder) { newOrder in
        //dataStore.reportItems.sort(using: newOrder) // previous call to Apple's sort method
        dataStore.sortReportBy(comparator: newOrder[0])
    }
```

Then, in my dataStore, I use the first comparator provided by Apple as the main field, but can refer to other fields also:

```
    func sortReportBy(comparator: KeyPathComparator<MyApp.ReportResponse>) {
        let keyPath = comparator.keyPath
        let isForwardSort = comparator.order == .forward
        if keyPath == \ReportResponse.unitName {
            reportItems.sort(by: {
                if $0.unitName != $1.unitName {
                    if isForwardSort {
                        return $0.unitName < $1.unitName
                    }
                    return $0.unitName > $1.unitName
                }
                return $0.name < $1.name
            })
        }
        else if keyPath == \ReportResponse.name {
            // etc.
```

It's not beautiful code but it fulfills my need. (Apple passed the other comparators besides the first one in an order that was not helpful to me, and I needed to closely control the secondary sort parameters). For the sake of the question in the OP, I also tested using a variable unrelated to my ReportResponse, and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks. Will try when I get time